# De que forma podría guardar la firma de un cliente en un formulario php?

Tags: php, mysql

La idea es concreto es la siguiente:

El cliente llenará un formulario con diferentes opciones, y al final el debe firmar a puño y letra, pero deseo que esa firma se guarde como una imagen en mi base de datos MySQL.

Aqui viene mi duda: Se puede hacer con una tablet con lapiz digital?

Necesito un hardware externos para este fin?

Comment: tardes yo tambien tengo que hacer un trabajo con firma en una tablet de firma pero no se cual es la libreria que hay que utilizar me puedes ayudara porfa muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes integrar esta librería, es a base de JavaScript: https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad

Posteriormente guardarías la ruta de la imagen en tu base de datos. Aunque sí poner en tus términos y condiciones de tu sitio web un simple checklist podría funcionar como firma, ya que aceptaría los términos y condiciones. Tiene casi la misma validez que un contrato físico.

Comment: La idea es que el cliente haga la firma a puño y letra a traves de un PAD o una TABLET.

Comment: Entonces con la librería es posible.

Comment: Es factible usarlo en una tablet normal, o tengo que comprar una en especial?

Comment: yo utilizo esa libreria para una aplicacion que tengo desarrollada para el control de jornada laboral (fichar) y firman con el dedo en el movil o en la oficina con un tablet